# I cannot update fill color when hovering over a feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I am currently learning OpenLayers library from their tutorials and examples.

In the "Custom Hit Detection", I tried to do some modifications to the script and try to modify a circle style when moving the cursor over it. But when I try to update the render by calling feature.changed(), it does nothing, but console logs shows fill color has been changed properly.

Can anyone give me some insight into this issue?

customHitDetection.js

```
const columbusCircleCoords = ol.proj.fromLonLat([-73.98189, 40.76805]);
const labelTextStroke = 'rgba(120, 120, 120, 1)';
const circleColor = 'rgba(233, 120, 120, 0.2)';
const labelText = 'Columbus Circle';

let pointerOverFeature = null;

const renderLabelText = (ctx, x, y, stroke) => {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,1)';
  ctx.strokeStyle = stroke;
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.font = `bold 30px verdana`;
  ctx.filter = 'drop-shadow(7px 7px 2px #e81)';
  ctx.fillText(labelText, x, y);
  ctx.strokeText(labelText, x, y);
};

const renderShapeColor = (ctx, stroke) => {
  ctx.fillStyle = stroke;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.strokeStyle = stroke;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.font = `bold 30px verdana`;
  ctx.filter = 'drop-shadow(7px 7px 2px #e81)';
};

const circleFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Circle(columbusCircleCoords, 50),
});

const bigCircleFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Circle(ol.coordinate.add(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-3, 40.76805]), [20, 20]), 1000000),
});

const pointCircleFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([3, 50])),
    color: 'blue',
});

pointCircleFeature.setStyle(
    new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 20,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: pointCircleFeature.get('color'),
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'gray',
          width: 1,
        }),
      }),
        hitDetectionRenderer(coordinates, state) {
          const [x, y] = coordinates[0];
          const ctx = state.context;
          ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
          ctx.stroke();
        },
    })
);

circleFeature.set('label-color', labelTextStroke);
circleFeature.set('shape-color', circleColor);

bigCircleFeature.set('label-color', labelTextStroke);
bigCircleFeature.set('shape-color', circleColor);

circleFeature.setStyle(
  new ol.style.Style({
    renderer(coordinates, state) {
      const [[x, y], [x1, y1]] = coordinates;
      const ctx = state.context;
      const dx = x1 - x;
      const dy = y1 - y;
      const radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

      const innerRadius = 0;
      const outerRadius = radius * 1.4;

      const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(
        x,
        y,
        innerRadius,
        x,
        y,
        outerRadius
      );
      gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255,0,0,0)');
      gradient.addColorStop(0.6, 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)');
      gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255,0,0,0.8)');
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
      ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,1)';
      ctx.stroke();

      renderLabelText(ctx, x, y, circleFeature.get('label-color'));
      renderShapeColor(ctx, circleFeature.get('shape-color'));
    },
    hitDetectionRenderer(coordinates, state) {
      const [x, y] = coordinates[0];
      const ctx = state.context;
      renderLabelText(ctx, x, y, circleFeature.get('label-color'));
      renderShapeColor(ctx, circleFeature.get('shape-color'));
    },
  })
);

bigCircleFeature.setStyle(
  new ol.style.Style({
    renderer(coordinates, state) {
      const [[x, y], [x1, y1]] = coordinates;
      const ctx = state.context;
      const dx = x1 - x;
      const dy = y1 - y;
      const radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

      const innerRadius = 0;
      const outerRadius = radius * 1.4;

      const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(
        x,
        y,
        innerRadius,
        x,
        y,
        outerRadius
      );
      gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255,0,0,0)');
      gradient.addColorStop(0.6, 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)');
      gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255,0,0,0.8)');
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
      ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,1)';
      ctx.stroke();

      renderShapeColor(ctx, bigCircleFeature.get('shape-color'));
    },
    hitDetectionRenderer(coordinates, state) {
      const [x, y] = coordinates[0];
      const ctx = state.context;
      renderShapeColor(ctx, bigCircleFeature.get('shape-color'));
    },
  })
);

const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
      visible: true,
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source:  new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [circleFeature, bigCircleFeature, pointCircleFeature],
      }),
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: columbusCircleCoords,
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});

map.on('pointermove', (evt) => {
  const featureOver = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, (feature) => {
    if (feature === bigCircleFeature) {
            console.log("BIG");
            feature.set('label-color', 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
            feature.set('shape-color', 'rgba(0, 120, 120, 0.2)');
    } else if (feature === circleFeature) {
            console.log("SMALL");
            feature.set('label-color', 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
            feature.set('shape-color', 'rgba(0, 120, 120, 0.2)');
    } else if (feature === pointCircleFeature) {
            console.log("POINT");
            console.log(feature.getStyle().getImage().getFill().getColor());
            feature.getStyle().getImage().getFill().setColor('rgba(255,255,255,1)');
            console.log(feature.getStyle().getImage().getFill().getColor());
            feature.changed();
    }
    
    return feature;
  });

  if (pointerOverFeature && pointerOverFeature != featureOver) {
    circleFeature.set('label-color', labelTextStroke);
    circleFeature.set('shape-color', circleColor);
    pointCircleFeature.getStyle().getImage().getFill().setColor('blue');
    pointCircleFeature.changed();
  }
  pointerOverFeature = featureOver;
});
```

customHitDetection.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>OpenStreepMap layer using OpenLayers</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.12.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.12.0/css/ol.css"/>
    <!-- Pointer events polyfill for old browsers, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/elm-pep"></script>
    <!-- The lines below are only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=fetch,requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,TextDecoder"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/3.18.3/minified.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/arc.js/v0.1.0/arc.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        margin: 0;
        height: 720px;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>
    <script src="resources/customHitDetection.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ol.style.Circle` is not automatically re-rendered after changes to the fill.  Updating the radius will force a re-render `feature.getStyle().getImage().setRadius(feature.getStyle().getImage().getRadius());`  as will the non-API render() method
`feature.getStyle().getImage().render();`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it does not solve the issue. Now, circle color changes when cursor is over it AND update the view changing zoom value. But writing `view.setZoom(view.getZoom());` does nothing and `view.setZoom(view.getZoom() + 1);` updates whole map and it's not good. I have seen the way to do this is by using select interaction, but I wonder if this alternative is valid.